# How to get a shared type in multiple wcf class libraries to be the same for all the clients

Tags: c#, wcf

Let me explain my question : i have a shared type let's call it "SharedType".
Then I have multiple wcf services under multiple namespaces using that type example : Service1.SharedType , Service2.SharedType ... Can i serialize all of these under the same xml namespace and name?? each of my clients have a type of name "SharedType" and namespace "www.datacontract.org".I noticed that the first service to run encounters no problem i can use SharedType on the respectif client.When i start the second, i cannont use that type on it's client , it tells me that the type is not expected and that i should use a resolver...
Is there a way to force the acceptance, i need them this way on purpose.
And yeah i use wcf class library not wcf applications.

Thank you Smile | :)

Comment: I'm not following. If you're referencing same `SharedType` definition, there's no reason for it to not work.

Comment: all the services use "Common.SharedType" whish is added to all of them as link. now when you generate the clients, all of them will have a member called SharedType under the same namespace.this compiles, but when you want to use that type only the first launched client can use it, for the others it's unexpected type.i need the clients to know that SharedType has multiple MetadataSources so they can expect different server-side namespaces.i'm using a wcf class library then generate my client with svcUtil.

Comment: A type is consist of class name and namespace. Service1.SharedType and Service2.SharedType are different types even though the codes look alike. Why would you have those mess in the first place?

Comment: @user2231260 You cannot include that type in both output librariess, since they'll have different signatures as Andy H mentioned. What you should do is to create a separate dll file with common types, which both of your projects would reference to. Every common definition should be defined externally. Follow `DRY` principle.

Comment: It's an existing big project and i can't go modifying it's entire logic.I think may be using dataContractResolver for each Service should resolve this ,No?

Answer (score 1):

The way to fix this problem is to put the shared types into a dll. Then reference that DLL in the server project and then client project. As long as you use the same DLL you should be fine. (Assuming you're using data contract serializer here.)

Here is an example of how you'd do this sort of thing. Notice how Person is in the DLL.
https://github.com/Aelphaeis/MyWcfPipeExample

If you happen to be using a duplex then you can look at this example instead. Same thing without the complex type.
https://github.com/Aelphaeis/MyWcfDuplexPipeExample

Another way to fix this problem is to actually take the object and serialize it into a string and remove the name spaces. Pass it to the service and deserialize it manually. This is rather clumbersome and I don't recommend this unless you cannot use data contract serializer and you're using older web services (.asmx from 3.5); however, if you are dead set on this crazy idea you can do the following :

```
public class NoNameSpaceXmlWriter : XmlTextWriter
{
    public NoNameSpaceXmlWriter(TextWriter output) : base(output) { Formatting = Formatting.Indented; }
    public override void WriteStartDocument() { }
    public override void WriteStartElement(string prefix, string localName, string ns) { base.WriteStartElement("", localName, ""); }
}
```

and the usage would be something like this:

```
new XmlSerializer(ret.GetType()).Serialize(new NoNameSpaceXmlWriter(ms), ret);
```

where ret is some random object.

Comment: Thanks a lot.I appreciate the explanation, the DLL containing types solution worked.Another way (the solution i had to implement because we were in a hurry and because the solution has to remain unchanged ) is to grab every entring type from client to service and recast manually into the local type by affecting each field of that type and then use the local one.Hate to have to do such dumb solution but i can't help it.Anyway thanks a lot this will certainely help in the future :)

Comment: ah, sorry I didn't clue into it yesterday! Its unfortunate I couldn't help you yesterday~